# Generating a tree diagram from an XSD file

Tags: xml, xsd, diagram

I would like to generate a tree diagram out of an XML schema definition. Liquid XML Studio has a visual XSD tree editor, and lets me save my tree as a .png file, which fulfills some of my needs. But I am wondering if there is a tool out there that lets users convert XSD files to web pages, where the diagram can be clicked, expanded, and collapsed, and possibly even support URL fragments, so that I could link to a particular complexType, and clicking on the link would jump to that part of the diagram.

Is there a tool out there that does any of these things?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/2486758/2799037 for a similar question without the online requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oxygen XML does most if not all of what you need. From the [website blurb](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_schema_editor.html):

> It is possible to generate HTML
>   documentation pages from XML Schema
>   files. The documentation includes
>   images representing the models for the
>   elements, attributes, types, a.s.o.
>   The documentation is obtained with
>   just a couple of clicks even for
>   schemas that include or import other
>   schemas. For large schemas a generate
>   chunks option is available that will
>   output each global schema component
>   description (element, attribute, type,
>   etc.) on a separate page.

An example HTML documentation page is given, the link to which is broken. Try Google's cached copy:

http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:g_RCqsDpZ2YJ:www.oxygenxml.com/personal.html+http://www.oxygenxml.com/personal.html

Answer (score 5):

The open source command line java application **xsdvi** creates an interactive diagram in SVG format from an XML Schema Definition. The generated SVG file can be displayed by a modern web browser where the user can expand and collapse the tree by mouse clicking.

Here is an example of a generated diagram

http://xsdvi.sourceforge.net/ipo.svg

The software can be downloaded from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xsdvi/

See also [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339653/757777)

Answer (score 1):

[Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/Xsd-Documentation-Generator.aspx) can also generate HTML Docs.
Have a look at the [schema library](http://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/) for some sample output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Liquid XML has a XSD dependancy viewer. I find it realy useful for finding unresolved includes as they are marked in red.
[image]