# How to visualize an XML schema programatically?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have made an XML Schema - all the code basically - and was wondering if there is a way that the code can generate something like this:

[image]

If so how can I do it?

Comment: If you are using Confluence, check out the new XSD viewer plugin [in the Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/nl.avisi.confluence.plugins.xsdviewer)

Comment: it looks like the [tool I found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486758/how-to-visualize-an-xml-schema/22236135#22236135) is the one the OP had a screen shot of.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? If you just looking for a software recommendation, there are better StackExchange sites for that.

Answer (score 74):

The open source command line java application **xsdvi** creates an interactive diagram in SVG format from an XML Schema Definition. The generated SVG file can be displayed by a modern web browser where the user can expand and collapse the tree by mouse clicking.

Here is an example of a generated diagram

http://xsdvi.sourceforge.net/ipo.svg

The software can be downloaded from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xsdvi/

It can be run as follows (assuming Java is installed and `java.exe` is in the path):-

1. Go to the `dist/lib` folder.
2. Run the following command `java -jar xsdvi.jar <input1.xsd> [<input2.xsd> [<input3.xsd> ...]] [style]`

Comment: usage: `java -jar xsdvi.jar <input1.xsd> [<input2.xsd> [<input3.xsd> ...]] [style]` (from xsdvi.zip /res/readme.txt)

Comment: The only problem with this tool is the SVG generated is a bit slow. Like, if I 'collapse all' after opening it takes about fifteen seconds for it collapse. But its free...so...

Comment: Great open source software! the only issue is that the SVG will be big file and click on the +/- button will become very slow(3-5 seconds)

Comment: Great tool! I wonder if it's possible to make such transformation XSD->SVG with XSLT

Comment: You guys have to buy a faster computer :) It works ok for me, really nice tool

Comment: It seems it wasn't updated more than 10 years... XSD definition is not evolving too fast, but this still rises the question if the format support is up to date.

Comment: Tried this and XSD Diagram with a complex XSD 700kb and 150kb approximately. This tool generate exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space even after giving over a GB of memory. I'd recommend XSD Diagram for interactive viewing after trying these two

Comment: This tool created 1.2 GiB svg file which is doubly usable, as it loads forever :/

Comment: Still works in 2023!

Answer (score 62):

[XSD Diagram](http://regis.cosnier.free.fr/?page=XSDDiagram) is free (GNU open license), doesn't need to be built, and gives an interactive diagram.
You just open the file and Add the types you want on the (initially blank) diagram.
Pretty straight forward.

[image]

Comment: nice one, runs even with latest Mono-MDK (4.0) on OSX. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Brilliant little software. Super light weight and does not need JRE, fast. Love it.

Comment: This is pretty good.

Comment: And it's in the [default ubuntu repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xsddiagram) - no idea why the official website doesn't mention this?

Comment: Is there an updated version? This bases on .NET Framework 2.0/3.5, which both are deprecated.

Comment: @Max, what happens when you download 2.0 and run it with that?

Comment: @toddmo 2.0 is no longer supported, so I am not allowed to use this version any longer. This is very restricted in companies.

Comment: @Max, I know this doesn't help you, but it might be time to just give up on `xml/xsl/xslt`. I said goodbye and started using `json` and never looked back. There's no tooling in VS Code for xml gridviews anymore, for example. The xslt libraries are flaky and pickings are slim b/c very few are working on it any more. If you feel you must download the source code and rebuild it with latest .Net, please put it up on Github as public so you (and the world) will always have it.

Comment: @toddmo you are right in general, we never used xml as data format again since this project, json is the better standard, total agree. But - this is an old project, still running, and the replacement of xml by json would have a big impact, so no option.

Answer (score 32):

You can use [XMLGrid](http://xmlgrid.net/)'s Online viewer which provides a great XSD support and many other features:

- Display XML data in an XML data grid.
- Supports XML, XSL, XSLT, XSD, HTML file types.
- Easy to modify or delete existing nodes, attributes, comments.
- Easy to add new nodes, attributes or comments.
- Easy to expand or collapse XML node tree.
- View XML source code.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 30):

The **Oracle JDeveloper 11g** built-in viewer is in my view superior to the one available for **Eclipse** (which, in addition to other unfavourable comparison points I could only get to install for **Indigo** but not for **Juno**). If I am not mistaken Oracle [makes the JDeveloper available for free](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html) (only requires registration at the OTN).

[image]

Comment: JDeveloper (Java edition) did the job for me, tried other softwares mentioned here but no luck.

Comment: Watch out when using it on the OSX: after unpacking the .zip file the JDeveloper.app won't start because of a file permission problem. You must set the executable bit on
    /Applications/jdeveloper/JDeveloper.app/Contents/MacOS/JDeveloper.

Then, it still won't start until you save the path of your JDK in ~/.jdev_jdk like this:
    echo $JAVA_HOME > ~/.jdev_jdk

Comment: This works like a charm! We used to use XMLSpy for adding pictures of the API which led to some awkward moments of finding someone who had a license, finding someone who had a trial, or finding someone who didn't already install the trial to make the pictures. It seemed silly to buy a $500 program only for a couple of pictures.

Answer (score 24):

On Linux (with mono, available via `apt-get` on Debian) and Windows:

- [XSDDiagram](http://regis.cosnier.free.fr/?page=XSDDiagram) (runs on Mono as well)

If you are on Windows I recommend you have a look at:

- [XMLPad3 from WMHelp](http://www.wmhelp.com/) or

Both tools are free and both are able to provide similar visualizations as shown in your example.

Comment: XSD Diagram is really nice. Thanks. One thing to note: When you load up an XSD, the app doesn't show anything on the diagram tab, not even the root element. I thought it was broken, but it turns out you just have to explicitly tell it which elements to show.

Comment: best answer !  for linux,  `sudo apt install xsddiagram` to install XSDDiagram

Answer (score 20):

If you need a simple, more text-oriented documentation of your XSD, check out [xs3p](http://xml.fiforms.org/xs3p/) - a XSLT stylesheet that will transform your XSD into more readable HTML format. Quite nice, and totally free.

If that's not enough, check out some of the commercial tools out there - I personally prefer the [Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Xml-Schema-Editor.aspx) - not as expensive as others, and quite as capable!

Comment: The Community Edition has been superseded by the non-free Starter Edition for USD 106.90 per annum.

Comment: @Andrew Swan: what a pity.... still - Liquid XML is a great tool

Comment: Currently (March 2013) there's a fully functional free 30 days trial version available (again).

Comment: The xs3p link referenced above does not work. Anyone know where it went?

Answer (score 15):

That picture is generated from a XML Schema editing tool, such as [Altova's XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-schema-editor.html).

There are a number of XML tools around, all of which will include a Graphical XSD Viewer.  I mentioned XML Spy simply because it is the brand leader.  Also many general IDEs like Eclipse, Visual Studio and Oracle JDeveloper will be able to do this trick.

Comment: In Eclipse you can right-click the XSD file and choose Open With -> Other... -> XML Schema Editor, although the editor is a little unresponsive browsing a 340kb file.

Comment: JDeveloper XSD View looks fine.

Answer (score 6):

We offer a tool called [DocFlex/XML XSDDoc](http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/xsddoc/) that allows you to enjoy both things at once:

- To have diagram represetation of your XML schema
- To have all those diagrams embedded (and hyperlinked) in a highly sophisticated XML schema documentation

The diagrams in fact are generated not by us, but by [Altova XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/). We implemented an **[Integration with XMLSpy](http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/XMLSpy/)** (with the full support of all diagram hyperlinks):

[image: XML schema documentation with diagrams generated by XMLSpy]

Here you can see the full this doc: [http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/xsddoc/examples/html/XMLSchema/index.html](http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/xsddoc/examples/html/XMLSchema/index.html?schemas/XMLSchema_xsd/complexTypes/namedAttributeGroup.html)

The whole thing provides a functionality not offered by any single vendor right now on the market!

Some our customers were so impressed that they purchased an extra license for XMLSpy only because of our tool. (That's no joke!)

---

Currently, we've also implemented similar integrations with other XML editors:

**[With <oXygen/> XML Editor](http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/OxygenXML/)**:

[image: XSDDoc with diagrams generated by <oXygen/> XML Editor]

See: [http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/OxygenXML/demo/html/xslt20/index.html](http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/OxygenXML/demo/html/xslt20/index.html?schemas/schema-for-xslt20_xsd/elements/for-each.html)

**[With Liquid XML Studio](http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/LiquidXML/)**:

[image: XSDDoc with diagrams generated by Liquid XML]

See: [http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/LiquidXML/demo/html/XMLSchema/index.html](http://www.filigris.com/docflex-xml/LiquidXML/demo/html/XMLSchema/index.html?schemas/XMLSchema_xsd/elements/global/redefine.html)

---

Concerning what all those diagrams depict... Essentially, they are all about content model of XSD elements (as well as other XSD components that lead to elements: complexTypes, element/attribute groups). It seems, there are two approaches here:

1. To show what a result content model (represented by the given component) would look. That's the approach of XMLSpy.
2. To show how a particular content model (of the given component) was derived from other components. That's the approach of <oXygen/> XML and Liquid XML.

I personally believe that the diagrams generated by XMLSpy are more useful.

Yet, there were no attempts so far (at least known to me) to depict graphically anything else contained in XML schemas, although one can imagine many...

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio 2013 has a pretty cool visualizer built in.

File -> Open -> File pick your .xsd and then drag elements from XML Schema Explorer onto the designer surface.

Comment: How to open designer surface?

Comment: Design surface should open up when you do File -> Open -> pick .xsd file.

At that point your xml schema isn't displayed yet, so the designer surface is sort of empty... 

It will open up as a blank tab with some instructions on what to do. 
The text reads "Visualize nodes in your XML schema set by dragging them from the XML Schema Explorer onto the design surface"

You have to click on that word XML Schema Explorer it's a link that will open up a tab on the side (that tab will then contain your xml schema pieces which you can drag onto the designer surface)

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be a feature that's available only on the Enterprise  edition of the VS. I've not tried with other VS editions.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 also can show XSD structure.

Answer (score 5):

There is a new free-to-use webtool, where you can view any xml schema:

[Online XML Schema Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seCHz.png)

[www.xml-tools.net](http://www.xml-tools.net/)

It's written completely in JavaScript, so it's running in most modern browsers.

Comment: I can't see any toolbar menu on the top in google chrome ?

Comment: Please tell me OS and browser version - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach- download the [freemind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemind/) and [CAM XML Template Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/camprocessor/).
Then open CAM XML, create new Template from XML, View -> View Template As Mind Map

  Pros of this solution:

- It works locally, so secret files can be processed,
- totally free of charge,
- open source.

Cons:

- Quite unstable with large (more than 20sh MB) files.

Answer (score 1):

Try my xsd-viewer available from https://github.com/santhosh-tekuri/jlibs.

Comment: Trying this but http://deadlock.netbeans.org/maven2 gives a 404 error, and if I use the org-netbeans-swing-outline JAR file from NetBeans 6.9.1, I get an NPE at DefaultRenderDataProvider.java:49

Comment: deadlock.netbeans.org/maven2 is down. now I used my personal repository. try with new sources...

Answer (score 1):

We use Liquid XML Studio, it provides a intuitive editable representation of an XSD schema. It also shows the annotations inline, which we find very useful and the split code/gfx view is invaluable when writting or editing an XSD.

[image: Liquid XML Studio XSD Editor]

Answer (score 0):

If someone works with IBM Rational Application Developer then XSD browser is built in it.

Answer (score 0):

Grid-ML Schema Viewer is great for searching and visualizing XML Schemas: https://gridml.com/xml-schema-viewer. I find it better than other tools when it comes to large schemas or when browsing through a diagram is not feasible. The tool also allows you to copy the XPath or JSON path of the selection item.

[Grid-ML Schema Search Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4B5S.png)