# Where can I get complete set of javax.persistence properties

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

Where can I get complete set of javax.persistence properties. which I can use in persistence.xml in JPA 2.1.

I have tried more that half a day. I have got only few properties from JPA specification and remaining properties are vendor specific. But I want all JPA properties, is there any class or interface which holds all of them? all of the sites are showing vendor specific properties either Hibernate or EclipseLink. But to achieve vendor independency I have to use JPA properties only.

Comment: Have you tried: https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jpa+persistence.xml+properties+reference

Comment: I have tried more that half a day. I have got only few properties from JPA and remaining properties are specified in vendor specific properties. But I want all JPA properties, is there any class or interface which holds all of them?

Comment: Just now I have gone through your link also @DonovanMuller but all of the sites are showing vendor specific properties either Hibernate or EclipseLink. But to achieve vendor independency I have to use JPA properties only.

Comment: [Here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/index.html) is the XML Schema of `persistence.xml` for the various JPA spec versions. For a visual view of the XSD, go [here](http://xmlgrid.net/view/xsdViewer.html) and use the relevant URL for the JPA version you're using. Also see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm) for the Oracle guide on how to configure your `persistence.xml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foot of [this page](http://datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jpa/emf.html#Standard_JPA_Properties) ("Standard JPA Properties") or just look in the JPA spec!

Answer (score 0):

The definitive reference would be the XSD document for `persistence.xml`.
Go [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/index.html) and select the relevant link for the version of JPA you are using.

For a more visual view, you can use XMLGrid's [XSD viewer](http://xmlgrid.net/view/xsdViewer.html) (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22236135/2408961) answer). Choose "By URL" and paste the relevant XSD link as per above. You will then be able to view all possible (JPA specific) options available to you.

[image]

Comment: except that the XSD lists explicit parts of the persistence-unit, NOT properties (where is javax.persistence.jdbc.* for example?). He wants what goes into "properties", nothing else